# Axios error in react app , Getting an error in Banner.js when I am using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, axios

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

GET http://localhost:3000/discover/tv?api_key=500179a347e1027821840c9690d80634&with_networks=213 404 (Not Found)

Banner.js

```
import axios from 'axios';


function Banner(props) {
const [movie,setMovie] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
   async function fetchData(){
     const request = await axios.get(props.url);
     
    setMovie(
     request.data.results[
       Math.floor(Math.random() * request.data.results.length - 1)
     ]
    )
    return request;
   }
   fetchData();
 }, [])


console.log(movie)


   return (
     <header>

     </header>
   );
}

export default Banner;
```

axios.js

```
import axios from "axios" ; 

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3',
})

export default  instance ;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react"
import './App.css';
import Row from "./Row";
import requests from "./requests";
import Banner from './Banner';
import Nav from './Nav';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav/>
      <Banner url = {requests.fetchNetflixOriginals}/>
      <Row 
      title = "Netfilx Originals" 
      url = {requests.fetchNetflixOriginals}
      isLargeRow 

      />
```

Comment: Are you running the server that has the path http://localhost:3000/discover/tv?api_key=500179a347e1027821840c9690d80634&with_networks=213? We have no way of validating this URL. It's on your machine.

Comment: yes i am running it on localhost:3000

Comment: OK, and the whole path is being served? Where is the code that implements this route `/discover/tv` and how is it being run?